# Referencing objects in java

Tags: java

In java, what is the difference between following 2 usage,

```
Employee e1 = new Employee();  
1.Employee e2 = (Employee)e1.clone();  
2.Employee e2 = e1;
```

In second case, I think e2 reference to the object that e1 also reference. So, they have the same same object with different reference number(may be memory address).

How about first case? Do e1 and e2 have both different object and reference?

Comment: If `Employee` is Cloneable, then it should be a *copy*. Otherwise you get an Exception.

Answer (score 3):

The first creates a new object by cloning the data of the original object - the class must implement the `Clonable` interface (a good example is `java.util.Calendar`).

The second is merely another reference to the *same* object.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are instantiating a new object and store the reference in e1.

suppose you are changing the salary in this next step `e1.setSalary(10000);`

then if `e1` object is cloned,
`Employee e2 = (Employee)e1.clone();` a new instance with salary as current value stored in e1 will be saved.
basically `e2` will be a new instance of Employee Class and whose salary is `10000`

if you later change the salary of `e2` it won't affect `e1`.
e.g.. `e2.setSalary(2000);` then salary in e1 would remain the same **e1 -> 10000** whereas for **e2 -> 2000**

In the third step, you are referencing e1 to e2,i.e. e2 would point to an instance which was referenced by e1, e1 and e2 would point to same instance... **so the cloned object will be like object without reference which is eligible for gc to act upon**

For getting to know more about clone, you could refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834683